# SQL Determine the teams having same members

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an interesting problem.

I've some teams with a team leader stored in one table and the members of teams are stored in child table. I want to determine the teams that have same members.

```
TEAMS
TEAM_ID    LEADER_ID
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2

MEMBERS
TEAM_ID MEMBER_ID
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   3
2   4
2   5
3   1
3   3
3   4
4   5
4   6
4   7
```

I was able to write this query to determine the formations and now I am clueless how to proceed.

```
SELECT
    TEAM_ID,
    (
        SELECT
            CONVERT (VARCHAR, MEMBER_ID) + ', '
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    TEAM_ID,
                    LEADER_ID AS MEMBER_ID
                FROM
                    TEAMS
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT
                        TEAM_ID,
                        MEMBER_ID
                    FROM
                        MEMBERS
            ) FORMATIONS
        WHERE
            TEAM_ID = MT.TEAM_ID
        ORDER BY
            MEMBER_ID FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) AS MEMBERS
FROM
    TEAMS MT
```

As it is clear that team id 1 and 3 are same, how can the lowest ID of the duplicate teams can be obtained.

i.e. the query should return the list of TEAM_IDs that are smallest per duplicate group (and only if they are duplicate)

In this scenario id 1 should be returned.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c845a/5

Comment: So under your definition, two teams are equivalent if they contain the same members, but the member assigned as leader can be different?

Comment: @Denziloe Yes... Exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are worse ways to approach this than stuffing the members into a string and comparing them.  So, I'll follow the route you have started.

All you need to do is to combine the members from the two tables, and then use that for the logic:

```
with m as (
       select team_id, member_id
       from members
       union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
       select team_id, leader_id
       from teams
      )
select *
from (select team_id, members, count(*) over (partition by members) as num_teams
      from (select t.team_id,
                   stuff( (select concat(',', m.member_id)
                           from m
                           where m.team_id = t.team_id
                           order by m.member_id
                           for xml path ('')
                          ), 1, 1, ''
                        ) as members
            from teams t
           ) t
     ) t
where num_teams > 1
order by members;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c845a/11) is your SQL Fiddle.

Note that string comparison works fine for this case, which is an *exact* match of members.  For superset relationships is doesn't work so well.

Comment: "There are worse ways to approach this than stuffing the members into a string and comparing them".. you mean to say "There are better ways to approach this than stuffing the members into a string and comparing them"?

Comment: and can the query be modified to return only row with id 1 .. and not both 1 and 3?

Comment: @Khan . . . Actually, combining the values together is really simply than other methods (although I would prefer a data type).  If you just want one row, then use `select members, min(team_id) from t group by members having count(*) > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, it uses CTE to get grouped teams wth its members listed as comma separated list.

Later it is used with `group by` to determine lowest ID of teams with same members. To ensure thhat there will be only duplicated teams, I used `having` clause.

```
;with cte as (
    select team_id,
           (select cast(member_id as varchar(5)) + ',' from @members innerMembers
            where team_id = m.team_id 
            and not exists(select 1 from @TEAMS
                           where leader_id = innerMembers.member_id)
            order by member_id
            for xml path('')) members
    from @members m
    group by team_id
)

select min(team_id), members from cte
group by members
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Not returning the result as desired....as you can see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e476/2/0... It should return 1 and 4 in this case (as I added a bit more data)...

Comment: Why 4 should be returned? It shouldnt accordingly to your descripiton...

Answer (score 0):

Using pure SQL.

The main idea is that two sets A and B being equal is defined by A being a subset of B and B being a subset of A.

And we can check whether B is a subset of A by getting the members of B which are in A, counting them, and checking whether this equals the count in A.

As this is a somewhat complicated step I simply did it by cross applying a subquery filtered to teams A and B. There may be a more elegant way.

```
WITH MembersAll AS
(
  SELECT Team_Id, Member_Id FROM Members
  UNION
  -- Consider leaders as members.
  SELECT Team_Id, Leader_Id AS Member_Id FROM Teams
),
-- Teams and any teams which are a subset of that team:
TeamSubsetTeam AS (
  SELECT
  ThisTeam.Team_Id,
  OtherTeam.Team_Id AS SubsetTeam_Id
  FROM Teams AS ThisTeam
  CROSS JOIN Teams AS OtherTeam -- Considering all pairs of teams.
  CROSS APPLY (
    -- Get the members in both teams,
    -- left join so that we have all members from a given team
    -- and all of the members in the other team that are in the given team
    -- then filter on the counts of these being the same.
    SELECT
    COUNT(MembersThisTeam.Member_Id) AS MemberCountThisTeam,
    COUNT(MembersOtherTeamInThisTeam.Member_Id) AS MemberCountOtherTeamInThisTeam
    FROM MembersAll AS MembersThisTeam
    LEFT JOIN MembersAll AS MembersOtherTeamInThisTeam
      ON MembersThisTeam.Member_Id = MembersOtherTeamInThisTeam.Member_Id
      AND MembersOtherTeamInThisTeam.Team_Id = OtherTeam.Team_Id
    WHERE MembersThisTeam.Team_Id = ThisTeam.Team_Id
  ) MemberCounts
  WHERE MemberCounts.MemberCountThisTeam = MemberCounts.MemberCountOtherTeamInThisTeam
),
-- Teams and any teams which are equivalent to that team (including itself):
TeamEquivalentTeam AS (
  -- From set theory, team A is equivalent to team B if
  -- team A is a subset of team B and
  -- team B is a subset of team A.
  SELECT
  Team_Id,
  SubsetTeam_Id AS EquivalentTeamId
  FROM TeamSubsetTeam
  WHERE Team_Id IN (
    SELECT SubsetTeam_Id FROM TeamSubsetTeam AS SubsetTeamSubsetTeam
    WHERE SubsetTeamSubsetTeam.Team_Id = TeamSubsetTeam.SubsetTeam_Id
  )
)
-- The specified post-processing step.
-- Doesn't seem particularly useful but you can do whatever you like
-- now you have the information in TeamEquivalentTeam.
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(EquivalentTeamId) AS FirstEquivalentTeam
FROM TeamEquivalentTeam
GROUP BY Team_Id
```

Returns:

```
FirstEquivalentTeam
1
2
4
```